# iOS: use calyer renderInContext to capture imageview lose quality

Tags: ios

I use calyer's renderInContext to create a capture to imageView, but I find it's losing quality. Where was I wrong?

code:
[image]

result:
[image]

edit:

the above image is displayed by a imageView with contentMode of `aspectFill` and clipToBounds.

the below image is process by the code I give, actually, I just want to clip the image to the same size as the imageView with contentMode of `aspectFill`, so I don't need clipToBounds to cause `offscreen-rendering`.

Comment: Where is the loss in quality ? The quality of the bottom image is actually better (downscale is much smoother).

Comment: Try lowering the interpolation quality of your context if you want to achieve the same "sharp" result of the top image.

Comment: Also when resizing an image you should work directly with the image itself (using its `draw` method) instead of drawing the layer of the imageView.

Comment: @deadbeef thanks，I tried your suggestion and it succeed, wow, I just don't understand why the image below is high quality than the above.

Answer (score 0):

according to the comment of @deadbeef, The quality of the bottom image is actually better (downscale is much smoother), which I don't know why, and as he suggest, try lowering the interpolation quality of your context if you want to achieve the same "sharp" result of the top image.

`context.interpolationQuality = .low`

I changed it to low, and it worked!